# Richfaces special code

Tags: java, firefox, jsf, richfaces, opera

I must use `rich:combobox` to display a combo.
In some cases I must add an empty `comboboxItem = new SelectItem("","")`.
This goes very well on IE8, Chrome, Safari.
It write `&nbsp;` with FF and Opera.
Looking at the richfaces code I see the class `ComboBoxBaseRenderer`, method `getItems` with a strange piece of code:

```
if("".equals(convertedValue)) {
 convertedValue = "\u00A0";
}
```

seems FF and Opera see `\u00A0` as a real blank char and translate it into a blank space.
How could be solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a JavaScript point of view Opera and Firefox are right here.

[White space](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.2) defined by ECMAScript 5.1, section 7.2

```
\u0009  Tab <TAB>
\u000B  Vertical Tab    <VT>
\u000C  Form Feed   <FF>
\u0020  Space   <SP>
\u00A0  No-break space  <NBSP>
\uFEFF Other category “Zs” Byte Order Mark Any other Unicode “space separator”  <BOM> <USP>
```

[White space defined by HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#whitespace) (Deprecated)

```
ASCII space (&#x0020;)
ASCII tab (&#x0009;)
ASCII form feed (&#x000C;)
Zero-width space (&#x200B;)
```

[Spaces characters defined by HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/common-microsyntaxes.html#space-character)

```
U+0020 SPACE, 
"tab" (U+0009), 
"LF" (U+000A), 
"FF" (U+000C), 
"CR" (U+000D).
```

Comment: Ok @karlcow but How I can fix this problem?

Comment: @Giant2 does it need to be invisible. `newString = aString.replace(/\s/g,'\u2009');` would that answer your need?